# Format anomaly between Excel versions (or screen resolutions)

Tags: excel, office365

## BACKGROUND:

I work on two computers:

**Computer #1 Dell XPS Tower (PC)**

- Windows 7
- Excel 2010
- Screen Resolution: 1280 x 1040

**Computer #2 Dell XPS 13 Laptop**

- Windows 10
- Excel Office 365
- Screen Resolution: QHD+ (3200x1800)

## PROBLEM:

When files are created or edited on Computer #2, then opened on Computer #1, cell contents appear to be padded at the bottom and cut off at the top of the cell.

[image: Cell Content Cut Off]

This occurs consistently with both new and existing files. The issue occurs regardless of which computer the file was created on -- once the file has been opened/edited on Computer #2, reopening the file on Computer #1 will yield the formatting issue.

The problem may be corrected by selecting all cells in the sheet and toggling the font size (i.e., click "increase font" then "decrease font" to return to original formatting).

While this is a relatively simple fix for myself, sharing files with this issue to clients and coworkers looks unprofessional; also, large files with several sheets become tedious to reformat with every iteration.

I have searched this site and google for a solution, but I cannot find other reports of this issue. I suspect, therefore, that this may be related to the QHD screen resolution or some related setting (presumably that is a less common scenario than moving between Excel versions).

## QUESTION:

Have you or someone you know encountered this problem?  Are you aware of a permanent solution (i.e., to prevent the issue from occurring, not to fix the problem after it occurs - I have that covered)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being an issue with the QHD screen resolution. 
 Changing the resolution to a lower resolution fixed the problem.  Not an ideal solution if you have paid extra for a QHD screen but at least I can send Excel files to clients again without worrying about basic formatting.